# Code blocks & lambdas c++11

Tags: c++, lambda

please, can any one explain me, how conditionalVariable will be stored in this case, to be used while check_calls_on_current_floor calling outside the condition block?

```
std::function<bool()> check_calls_on_current_floor;
if (/*Some condition*/)
{
    const int conditionalVariable = /*some value*/;

    check_calls_on_current_floor = [&](){ 
        return conditionalVariable == 10; };
}
check_calls_on_current_floor();
```

It seems like in this case we, can access this variable outside the condition block, in case we got lambda from there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using pointer-to-member to read value of cons object's field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19934348/using-pointer-to-member-to-read-value-of-cons-objects-field)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a dangling reference.  It's undefined behavior to make that call after the `if` block.  It's very similar to returning a reference to a local variable from a function. It's even more similar to this:

```
struct ref_holder
{
    ref_holder(const int & r) :ref(r) {}
    const int & ref;
};

int main()
{
    std::unique_ptr<ref_holder> ptr;
    if (true)
    {
        const int conditionalVariable = 10;

        ptr.reset(new ref_holder(conditionalVariable));
    }
    ptr->ref == 10; // undefined behavior
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's somewhat analogous to this:

```
int x = 0;
int* z = &x;
if (condition)
{
    int y = 1;
    z = &y;
}
```

If the condition holds, then `z` will be pointing to `y` which has gone out of scope.